# Differentiate banned from available instagram

Tags: go, instagram, instagram-api

I'm curious as how to differentiate a banned instagram username from an available one
Monitoring e.g. instagram.com/4 ( banned) and instagram.com/hinufwhi ( free ) both return a 404 status code, and using  https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/?__a=1 returns {} for banned and available accounts

I can't see anything in their docs and I was looking for an alternative to simulating a user login and trying to change the to targeted username, recording response to see if it's banned or available

Code in any language is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly the answer I wanted, but it seems from going to https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?query=USERNAME and iterating through the results, checked whether the username you want is there, could work.
Some issues I can see with this are that sometimes the name you search for aren't in the results, and it's not very effective.